selectCheckboxMenu in PrimeFaces is not sendind the data to the java class that manage the fron end
I have a project with Java and Primefaces.
The java class has a list of DevicesTypes that are loaded from the database and then the User can update them.
The problem is that the list is not received in the java back end class.
Is is lodad ok in the init method but is not updated when the user change its values in the front end.
This is the list to update:
private List<DeviceTypePartialInfoResult> defaultDeviceTypes = new ArrayList<>();

In the init() method it is loaded:
this.defaultDeviceTypes = deviceTypeSvc.findByPolicyTemplateId(policyTemplateId);
And when user press save() it is readed and saved to another list selectedTypes
List<DeviceTypePartialInfoResult> selectedTypes = this.defaultDeviceTypes;

I have the getter and setter for every variable.
The xhtml with Primefaces that create the view is the following:


<div class="ui-g-2 " style="width: 20em; min-height: 100px;">
   <p:column headerText="devicepolicytemplate" style="width:8em;"
      filterable="true" filterBy="#{dptd.deviceType}">
      <p:cellEditor>
         <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{dptd.deviceType.type}" />
         </f:facet>
         <f:facet name="input">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
               <h:outputLabel for="selectDeviceType" value="Device Types"
                  style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 14px;" />
               <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="selectDeviceType"  update="@form:aclform" dynamic="true"
                  value="#{devicePolicyTemplateDetailsView.defaultDeviceTypes}"
                  multiple = "true" emptyLabel="Please select..." updateLabel="true"
                  style="width:100%; min-height: 30px;" panelStyle="width:250px;"
                  scrollHeight="250" converter="converter" 
                  valueChangeListener="#{devicePolicyTemplateDetailsView.onDeviceTypeSelection(event)}">
                  <f:selectItems
                     value="#{devicePolicyTemplateDetailsView.allDeviceTypes}"
                     var="dt" itemLabel="#{dt.type}" itemValue="#{dt}" 
                     />
                  <p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="console.log(PF('selectDeviceType').getSelectedValue());" />
               </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </div>
         </f:facet>
      </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>
</div>

The selected items should be loaded in "defaultDeviceTypes" as it is requested in the xhtml.
Specifically the sentence
    value="#{devicePolicyTemplateDetailsView.defaultDeviceTypes}"

In the xhtml should loaded the values on the defaultDeviceTypes. But it doesn't happen.
This is the "converter" class:
@FacesConverter(value = "converter")
public class UniversalConverter implements Converter<Object> {
    
    private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<>();

    public UniversalConverter() {
        //Empty constructor
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                    return entry.getKey();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

¿Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks!
I tried with the following:

creating a new List of String instead of  ''DeviceTypePartialInfoResult''

add update="@form:aclform"

adding a Listener:
valueChangeListener="#{devicePolicyTemplateDetailsView.onDeviceTypeSelection(event)}"
to check if it is called when value is changed but the value of defaultDeviceTypes arrives without any modification from the fron end

I used a specific deviceTypeConverter to validate that was not the problem. Here is the code of the new converter
@FacesConverter("deviceTypeConverter")
public class DeviceTypeConverter implements Converter {
     @Override
     public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, DeviceTypePartialInfoResult value) {
         if (value == null) {
             return "";
         }
         // Assuming `DeviceTypePartialInfoResult` has a unique ID
         DeviceTypePartialInfoResult deviceType = (DeviceTypePartialInfoResult) value;
         return String.valueOf(deviceType.getId());
     }

     @Override
     public DeviceTypePartialInfoResult getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
         if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
             return null;
         }

         // Convert the string ID back to a `DeviceTypePartialInfoResult` using a service
         Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
         DeviceTypeService deviceTypeSvc = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{deviceTypeSvc}", DeviceTypeService.class);
         return deviceTypeSvc.findById(id); 
     }
 }



